# How to recognize the primary text of selected <MenuItem/> in ReactJS Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu and I would like to console log the primaryText of`<MenuItem/>` selected. How can I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

use `onChange(event: object, key: number, value: any)` function.

The event object has the information about the selected item.

you can try to

```
console.log(event.target.textContent)
```